# How to retrieve Firebase user data with Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have tried several ways but it always return me nil when I try to retrieve the user data, here is a sample code:

```
Button {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database(url: "SERVER_HERE").reference()
    var NSStringsNomeLocale: NSString = nomeLocale as NSString
    /*ref
        .child("locali")
        .child($nomeLocale.wrappedValue)
        .childByAutoId()
        .setValue(["createdById" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.email])*/
    var handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        print(auth.currentUser)
    }
} label: {
    Text("aggiungi")
}
```

How can I retrieve the user data like the email ?

Comment: Are you saying that `print(auth.currentUser)` always prints `nil`? If so, can you show why it should ever print something differently? I.e. are you signing the user in somewhere in your code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have checked and yess... I was logging in with wrong credentials, so no user were logged